# Rails 5 and up: How to render error pages with layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Rails 4 documentation explains [how to create a custom controller to render error pages](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.0/action_controller_overview.html#custom-errors-page) in section 14.3.

However, this section is conspiciously [missing from Rails 5 documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.0/action_controller_overview.html). The sections here end at 14.2.

Anybody know if there's a workaround?

GitHub has a 404 with layout, i.e. https://github.com/asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf

How is it that Rails doesn't support this anymore?

Comment: The feature has definately not been removed. Not sure why its missing from the later version of the guides. It could be that it was seen as being out of scope for the topic of the guide.

Comment: The guides are also just "how to guides" and the actual API documentation. There are plenty of features in Rails that are not covered by the guides (`ActiveRecord::Enum` for example) that are either covered by the ERB documentation or where  there are other community resources covering it.